# (0 , _reactNavigation.createAppContaner) is not a function Evaluating App.js Loading App.js

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, expo, native

I write code for google sign in.

expo react-native

I cannot solve this issue:

```
(0 , _reactNavigation.createAppContaner) is not a function
  Evaluating App.js
  Loading App.js
```

**`app.js`**

```
import LoginScreen from "./screens/LoginScreen";
import ProfileScreen from "./screens/ProfileScreen";

// react Navigation Setup
import { createAppContaner, createSwitchNavigator } from "react-navigation";

const MainNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
Login: { screen : LoginScreen },
Profile: { screen: ProfileScreen }
});

const App = createAppContaner(MainNavigator);

export default App;
```

**`./screens/LoginScreen`**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';

import * as Google from 'expo-google-app-auth';

const IOS_CLIENT_ID =
'375911328301-jlsms1k99gtk8qlcnkd6asqkrpsahphe.apps.googleusercontent.com';
//const ANDROID_CLIENT_ID =
//  "YOURCLIENTID";


export default class LoginScreen extends Component {
signInWithGoogle = async () => {
try {
  const result = await Google.logInAsinc({
    isoClientId: IOS_CLIENT_ID,
    //androidClientId:ANDROID_CLIENT_ID,
    success: ['profile', 'email'],
  });

  if (result.type === 'success') {
    console.log('LoginScreen.js', result.user.giveName);
    this.prop.navigation.navigate('Profile', {
      username: result.user.giveName,
    }); // after google login rederect to profile
    return result.accessToken;
  } else {
    return { cancelled: true };
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.log('LoginScreen.js', error);
  return { error: true };
}
};

render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Button title="Login" onPress={this.signInWithGoogle} />
  </View>
);
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
flex: 1,
backgroundColor: '#FFF',
alignItem: 'center',
justifyContent: 'center',
},
});
```

**`./screens/ProfileScreen`**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {Text, View, StyleSheet, Button} from "react-native";

export default class ProfileScreen extends Component{
render(){
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text> profilescreen </Text>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 , fontWeight:"bold" }}> welcome, 
{this.props.navigation.getParam("username")}</Text>
            <Button title="sign out" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Login")}/>
        </View>
    )
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container:{
    flex:1,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    alignItem : "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
}
});
```

I need it for my university project

Answer (score 0):

You have a spelling mistake in your import, use the following line to import createAppContainer.

```
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from "react-navigation";
```